# SharePoint Chart WebParts: Is there a way to add a timestamp?

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part

I've been working with the chart webparts, and was wondering if there is a way to add a timestamp to them.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this with a little JavaScript and CSS.

Use JavaScript to generate the current time, and to place it in an element on the page somewhere, perhaps using jQuery to make that bit easier (for instance, placing it somewhere adjacent to the chart in the DOM), and position it using CSS absolute positioning to place it over the chart.

If you know C# server side programming you could go a step further and override the ChartWebPart class and add the timestamp at the server side.

Comment: Thank you!  One more question: can Javascript access the lastitemmodified date property of the list?  That's what I need to be visible.

Comment: You could use SPServices (a jQuery extension, helps you query SharePoint data) to pull out the last modified date - http://spservices.codeplex.com/ - you'll need to get the first item of the list that comes back, when sorted by modified date descending (if that makes sense).